# Как добавить в массив значения атрибута data у списка с множественным выбором?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

Я использую bootstrap-select.
Имеется следующий список, где значения option определяются в другом файле в зависимости от условия.

```
<select class="selectpicker selectpicker_analysis form-control" name="analysis[]" multiple title="Выберите анализы" data-live-search="true" data-size="7">     
</select>
```

option прописываются так:

```
echo '<option data-price = '.$row_s["Price_medtest"].' data-medtest = '.$row_s["ID_Medtest"].'>'.$row_s["Name_medtest"].'</option>';
```

Нужно значения атрибута data-medtest записать в массив и занести в $_POST.

Как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0):

У `option` есть прекрасный аттрибут `value`, значения которых и передаются на сервер, если он (`option`) выбран.
Надеюсь вы мысль поняли.

Comment: Знаю я про value)
Мне надо несколько значений передавать с option, поэтому использую data.

Comment: @VladPech ну так в чём проблема? Значение, которое вы пишете в `data-medtest`, пишете в `value` . Ведь именно про этот параметр data вы спрашиваете, а не про весь объект `data`

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл вот такое решение.

```
var array = [];
$('.selectpicker_analysis option:selected').each(function(i,item) {
   array.push($(item).data());
});
```

Результат `console.log(array);`

[image: Результат console.log(array)]